# How to get marker object from angular google maps without clicking it

Tags: google-maps-markers, angular-google-maps

I basically need to hide the markers on click of a button .I am using angular google maps and I want to retrieve the marker object of the markers present on the map. How can i get that.  In the below code, I am passing the markers json response and creating markers on map. Any help on this is much appreciated. Thanks!!

```
<agm-map 
  #AgmMap
  (mapReady)="initMap($event)">

  <agm-marker 
      *ngFor="let m of markers; let i = index"
      [latitude]="m.lat"
      [longitude]="m.lng"
      [label]="m.label"
      [markerDraggable]="m.draggable"
      (dragEnd)="markerDragEnd(m, $event)">



  </agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of accessing Google Maps Marker object directly i would propose to manipulate marker visibility via `Marker` component, `visible` property seems to be a good candidate for that purpose.

Assuming makers data is represented in the following format

```
markers = [
    { Id: 1, name: "Oslo", lat: 59.923043, lng: 10.752839, visible: true },
    { Id: 2, name: "Stockholm", lat: 59.339025, lng: 18.065818, visible: true },
    { Id: 3, name: "Copenhagen", lat: 55.675507, lng: 12.574227, visible: true },
    { Id: 4, name: "Berlin", lat: 52.521248, lng: 13.399038, visible: true },
    { Id: 5, name: "Paris", lat: 48.856127, lng: 2.346525, visible: true }
  ];
```

and markers are initialized like this:

```
<agm-marker *ngFor="let m of markers" [visible]="m.visible"  [latitude]="m.lat" [longitude]="m.lng" >
</agm-marker>
```

marker visibility could be changed on button click like this:

```
toggleMarker(index) {
   this.markers[index].visible = !this.markers[index].visible;
}


<button (click)="toggleMarker(0)">Toggle marker</button>
```

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-my88uc)